# Function for Domain of Differential Equatiion

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Domain of d.e y'=f(x,y) is Domain[f] Union Domain[1/f].
I want to make function in Mathematica which will give Domain of any d.e and plot it.

```
 DomainDJ[f_, vars_] := 
      Union[FunctionDomain[f, vars], FunctionDomain[1/f, vars]];
```

This function give us Domain of d.e , with region plot we can plot that `RegionPlot[DomainDJ, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

For example d.e y'=(y*Log[y])/x when we use that function, we will get good Plot but we cant see visual that from region point (0,1) is out .

I definited a new function

```
PlotDomainDJSP[f_, vars_, sp_] := 
  Module[{pddj = {}}, spt = Transpose[sp];
   amin = Min[spt[[1]]];
   amax = Max[spt[[1]]];
   bmin = Min[spt[[2]]];
   bmax = Max[spt[[2]]];
   aamin = Min[{0, amin}];
   aamax = Max[{-aamin, amax}];
   bbmin = Min[{0, bmin}];
   bbmax = Max[{-bbmin, bmax}];
   For[i = 1, i <= Dimensions[sp][[1]], i++, 
    pddj = Append[pddj, 
      ParametricPlot[{aamin - 1 + (spt[[1, i]] - aamin + 1)*t, 
        spt[[2, i]]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashing[Tiny]}]]; 
    pddj = Append[pddj, 
      ParametricPlot[{spt[[1, i]], 
        bbmin - 1 + (spt[[2, i]] - bbmin + 1)*t}, {t, 0, 1}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashing[Tiny]}]]; 
    pddj = Append[pddj, 
      ParametricPlot[{((aamax - aamin + 2)/300) Cos[
           t], ((aamax - aamin + 2)/300) Sin[t]} + sp[[i]], {t, 0, 
        2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]]];
   df = DomainDJ[f, vars];
   rpdj = 
    RegionPlot[
     df, {x, aamin - 1, aamax + 1}, {y, bbmin - 1, bbmax + 1}];
   Show[{rpdj, pddj}]];
```

which show us nice everything but first problem of that is you need manual get points which give 0/0 case. My first question is how to set in this program that we not manual get point in case 0/0 .

Then my next question is can i merge that 2x function for example when we do not have points in d.e which give case 0/0 program use first function else if we get point 0/0 program use second function and how would do it .

I want a compact program-function which will give us VISUAL domain of d.e so maybe with this my idea or something else , maybe it can be much simpler (but visual with points 0/0 also ! )

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you would use your function `PlotDomainDJSP` ?

Comment: Do you mean `PlotDomainDJSP[(y*Log[y])/x, {x, y}, {{0, 1}}]`? I think by example, @b.gatessucks meant the actual code.  What does the argument `sp` stand for, "singular points"?  Is it a list of points?  Such usage clues are essential for others to give good answers.

Comment: Ofc, for example d.e f=(yLogy)/x , try with second function 
'f = (y*Log[y])/x;
vars = {x, y};   
ssp = {{0, 1}};
PlotDomainDJSP[f, vars, ssp]  '

and you will get a square without point (0,1) ,

Comment: Try with another first function 
DomainDJ[f_, vars_] := 
  Union[FunctionDomain[f, vars], FunctionDomain[1/f, vars]];
RegionPlot[DomainDJ, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
Then region plot that , it will give a square without showing that point (0,1) is out , but if we check with next function 
RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[DomainDJ, {x, y}], {0, 1}]

we will get answer 
FALSE 

Which is ok, but i ask how to merge both of function and get one compact function for DOMAIN OF DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS